# Can we trick Python for Cygwin as being on the win32 platform? (to install PyBluez)

Tags: python, windows, cygwin

I want to use the Python packaged with Cygwin on Windows. I need to install PyBluez, a Bluetooth Python binding. I installed it with easy_install, no problem. I know that it works well with the Windows version of Python as I did the .exe install of PyBluez and made some tests.

However I do not want to use the Windows version of Python, but the one from Cygwin. But actually, the installation with easy_install or directly from the tarball does not works well (no error messages, but it is not fully installed). The reason seems simple: in several files, there are some conditional statements:

```
if sys.platform == 'win32':
...
elif sys.platform == 'linux2':
...
elif sys.platform == 'darwin':
...
```

Unfortunately, when I launch Python for Cygwin, the platform is:

```
$ python

>>> import sys
>>> sys.platform
'cygwin'
```

What is interesting to check is which platform we have when we launch Python for Windows from Cygwin:

```
$ /cygdrive/d/Programs/Python26/python -i

>>> import sys
>>> sys.platform
'win32'
```

We could have the idea of modifying some Python files in the PyBluez library so they could take into account both 'win32' and 'cygwin':

```
if sys.platform == 'win32' or sys.platform == 'cygwin':
...
```

Unfortunately, 1) it means modifying some files, and 2) it is not enough: in the case of PyBluez, when I import the library, we have in the __init__.py file:

```
if sys.platform == "win32":
    _dbg("trying widcomm")
    have_widcomm = False
    dll = "wbtapi.dll"
    sysroot = os.getenv ("SystemRoot")
    ...
```

os.getenv("SystemRoot") is correctly defined when launching Python for Windows, but is not defined with Python for Cygwin.

So, my question is: is there an easy way to trick Python for Cygwin in thinking it is launched from a win32 platform, with all the correct needed environment, without having to modify library setup files by hand?

Maybe it isn't possible at all? (Both version are on Windows, but they are compiled differently).

The question is not restricted to the installation of PyBluez, but also for other kind of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and succeeded in tricking python to do this by adding to the first python file in my app, e.g. **init**.py or similar

```
import sys
sys.platform='linux'
```

Not sure if it will work for you, but something to try